# Can an AIX user that appears in etc/group but not etc/passwd still log into a server?

Tags: aix, group, access-control, passwd

Looking at etc/group and etc/passwd files, I see accounts listed in various groups in the etc/group file that do not appear in the etc/passwd files. Can these accounts still log in to the AIX server?

Comment: Maybe their account is in a different repository (LDAP, NIS, etc) ?

Comment: Andrew, did you get a satisfactory answer to your question? If so, please "accept" the answer using the green checkmark next to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

While these accounts *may* be leftovers from an incomplete removal, it is also possible that they are being served externally from /etc/passwd. Check the output of `grep ^login /etc/pam.conf | grep account` (assuming AIX >= 5.3) to see if you have any PAM modules that could be supplying the account information. LDAP, NIS, and other 3rd-party software may be configured to provide account and/or authorization data.

Let me add a shortcut answer to the actual question that was asked (inspired by the appearance of the `getent` answer, because I'm not aware of a getent for AIX):

```
lsuser -a login rlogin USERNAME
```

... should query whatever account repositories have been configured and tell you whether USERNAME can log in or not.

Comment: rlogin attribute is pretty much irrelevant nowadays and should only apply to legacy rlogin/rsh/rcp tools and telnet - which simply shouldn't be used any more at all, period.

And for querying a user I prefer the more simple and generic `lsuser ALL|grep -i USERNAME` as it will also show which authentication is configured for a user, e.g. compat, kerberos or NIS and some more helpful details.

But you provided good points.

Comment: I'll have to double-check, but I'm pretty sure sshd wanted rlogin=true, and not just login=true. Could be an artifact of particular versions, though.

Comment: I had to go to the source to confirm:
"If sshd is built with the WITH_AIXAUTHENTICATE option (which is enabled by default) then sshd checks that users are permitted via the loginrestrictions() function, in particular that the user has the
"rlogin" attribute set.  This check is not done for the root account,
instead the PermitRootLogin setting in sshd_config is used."

Comment: see openbsd-compat/port-aix.c in sys_auth_allowed_user() checking for S_RLOGIN being set. S_RLOGIN is distinct from S_LOGIN in /usr/include/login.h

Comment: Interesting finding, will have to doublecheck - usually we disable this and ssh login still works just fine. FWIW, what AIX version did you check this against, and do you use the default AIX ssh packages? As since AIX 5.3something ssh comes with AIX by default. From what I found, this only seems to apply for pre AIX 5.2-era and afterwards rlogin attribute works as expected and only applies to rlogin/rsh and telnet.

Comment: 6100-09-05-1524 and openssh.base.server

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think the short answer is no.</strike> Generally no, but see Jeff's answer. However you may want to run the AIX [chkgrp](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/grpck.htm) command which may clean up your `/etc/group` file as well as associated files.

Comment: The long answer is "yes", though. I have an account that is a counterexample - as the 'account' portion is handled by 3rd-party software.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ok. I forgot about PAM and NIS{,+}, so I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it depends on how whatever login process polices it. Unless AIX is very special there, the kernel does not check what is or is not in the group and passwd files.

If a root process gives someone a terminal and shell under an arbitrary user ID, they will more or less be logged in - some programs will not function correctly, though, since they will use the UID and/or primary GID as an argument to libc calls, and error out if there is faulty behaviour.